# How to send html-styled password reset email with django

Tags: python, django

I created an html-styled version of a password reset email to be set with django 4.0 located at 'registration/html_password_reset_email.html'. From other stackoverflows, I learned I needed to add the html_email_template_name parameter for the html version of the email to be sent. However, even with the below code, it is just the text version of the file that is being sent ('registration/password_reset_email.html'). It is definitely fining the registration/password_reset_email.html file, because edits I make to it are successfully emailed, but I can't get it to send the html version. Hints on what I'm doing wrong?

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView
from django.urls import reverse

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.homeview, name="homeview"),
    path('dashboard/', include('dashboard.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path("register/", views.register_request, name="register"),

    path('reset_password/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(
            template_name='registration/password_reset_form.html',
            html_email_template_name='registration/html_password_reset_email.html',
            email_template_name='registration/password_reset_email.html',  
        ), name="reset_password"), # Submit email form
    path('reset_password_sent/', auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(), name="password_reset_done"), # Email sent success message
    path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name="password_reset_confirm"), # Link to password reset form in email
    path('reset_password_complete/', auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(), name="password_reset_complete"), # Password successfully changed message
]
```

This is part of my settings.py file

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent.parent

# Take environment variables from .env file
environ.Env.read_env(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '.env'))

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'dashboard.apps.DashboardConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'crispy_forms',
    'mysite',
    'users',
    'corsheaders',
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },

    },
]
```

BASE_DIR resolves to: /Users/MYNAME/Documents/repos/begolden/mysite/templates
and my template files are at:
/Users/MYNAME/Documents/repos/begolden/mysite/templates/registration/html_password_reset_email.html

I tried setting EMAIL_BACKEND to django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend and the text version in registration/password_reset_email.html (not the html version) prints out to console. I also tried changing the html file to just say "Hello World", in case the original html was malformed. The text registration/password_reset_email.html still prints to console (not the html file location).

I think it isn't actually using the file locations I'm providing, because when I change the email_template_name like below, it doesn't read the new text 'registration/test.html'. It still reads the text at the default location 'registration/password_reset_email.html '. I find this confusing though, because it IS finding my custom text at 'registration/password_reset_email.html', which seems to imply that my folder structure is correct but PasswordResetView just isn't using the argument names I am giving it??

```
    path('password_reset/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(
       html_email_template_name='registration/html_password_reset_email.html',
            email_template_name='registration/test.html'
        ), name="password_result"),
```

Comment: How did you check that the HTML multipart is actually missing? To confirm the issue, as that could also be a malformed HTML ignored by the client, falling back to text/plain. Did you try to set `EMAIL_BACKEND` to `django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend` to check in your console logs if the HTML multipart is present or not? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/email/#console-backend

Comment: I didn't know that was a thing, but I just tried it and the text version in registration/password_reset_email.html (not the html version) prints out to console. I also tried changing the html file to just say "Hello World", in case the original html was malformed. The text registration/password_reset_email.html still prints to console (not the html file location).

Comment: I just added some more details in the main explanation above, based on this suggestion

Comment: I think I found something. You named your url `reset_password` but the name used by Django is `reset_password`. So I think your custom view is indeed not called and Django's view is used instead. I assume that when you proceed to password reset, you should notice that the URL is still `/accounts/password_reset/` instead of `/password_reset/`. Can you try setting `name='password_reset'` instead of `name='reset_password'`? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordResetView

Comment: You are right. I needed to change that url. This worked!

    path('accounts/password_reset/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(
            html_email_template_name='registration/html_password_reset_email.html',
            email_template_name='registration/password_reset_email.html'
        ), name="password_reset"), # Submit email form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You named your URL `reset_password`, while the name used by Django is [`password_reset`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordResetView). You have to use the same name, as it will be called by Django with `reverse('reset_password')`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...,
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    ...,
    path('reset_password/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(
            template_name='registration/password_reset_form.html',
            html_email_template_name='registration/html_password_reset_email.html',
            email_template_name='registration/password_reset_email.html',  
        ), name="password_reset"), # <-
    ...,
]
```

Also, beware to keep this URL pattern **after** `path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls'))`, as the URL name will clash and [the last one has the precedence](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns).

> When naming URL patterns, choose names that are unlikely to clash with other applications' choice of names. If you call your URL pattern comment and another application does the same thing, the URL that reverse() finds depends on **whichever pattern is last** in your project's urlpatterns list.